# program won't run when WebView is inserted, using Beginning Android 2 by Mark Murphy, followed instrutions on page 141

Tags: android, webview

For example (WebKit/Browser1), here is a simple layout with a WebView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<WebView android:id="@+id/webkit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do I create a class called browser1 or create a xlm file under layouts with the name Browser1, also is the WebKit directory necessary?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I create a class called browser1

Your `Activity` can be named whatever you want.

> or create a xlm file under layouts with the name Browser1

Your layout file can be named whatever you want.

> also is the WebKit directory necessary?

It is necessary for that book, because there are three separate WebKit examples (`Browser1`, `Browser2`, `Browser3`), meaning that in traditional computer filesystems, you need a directory to put the three of them in one place.